# Does numpy.fft2 results produce results that follow standard ordering as described in numpy.fft documentation?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I've read the documentation and searched Stack Overflow for the answer to this question, but can't find it. Sorry if it has already been answered.

I'm working with the results of an `np.fft.fft2(Z)` where `Z` is some 2d NumPy array. I would expect positive frequencies to be stored in values less than the Nyquist wavenumber in both x and y directions. From my tests, it seems this is the approach Matlab takes. In NumPy documentation they write positive frequencies are stored below the Nyquist number and negative frequencies above; this does not seem to be the case for `fft2`.

Some positive frequencies terms are stored at locations greater than the Nyquist wavenumber. For example, a mode at location (127,1) with associated amplitude stored at (1,127), will produce a 2D sinusoid with 4 peaks indicating that the wavenumber should be around 4, not 127.

I can't tell which is the positive and negative frequency in my example above because they are not following standard ordering.
So the main question I have is what kind of order does the `fft2` follow for storing positive and negative frequencies?

I didn't post any examples because my question is a universal one and shouldn't be problem specific.

---

```
import numpy as np
from heapq import nlargest

## Setting up a simple example
lx = 4.0
ly = 4.0;
lz = 1.5;
nx = 128;
ny = 128;
L = 1.0
H = .4

x = np.linspace(0, lx, nx);
y = np.linspace(0, ly, ny);

x0 = 2.0;
y0 = 2.0;
z1 = np.zeros([ny,nx])
zm= np.zeros([ny,nx])
for j in range(1,ny):
    for i in range(1,nx):
        if np.sqrt(abs(x[i] - x0)** 2 + abs(y[j] - y0) ** 2) < L:    
            if np.abs(x[i] - x0) < L:
                z1[j, i] = H * np.cos(np.pi * abs(x[i] - x0) / (2 *L))**2;

z1 = z1+np.transpose(z1)/2.0
## Here I take the fft    
nf = np.shape(z1)[0]/2
fz1 = np.fft.fft2(z1)
spec_fz1 = np.abs(fz1)**2
valmax = nlargest(1000, spec_fz1.flatten())
## Here I search for amplitude pairs above nyquist number   
for i in range(1,len(valmax),2):
    xy = return_xy(valmax[i], spec_fz1)
    if len(xy) >2:
        if ((xy[0] > nf or xy[1]> nf) and (xy[2] > nf or xy[3]> nf) ):
            print('both index locations above nyquist frequency')
    else:
        xy2 = return_xy(valmax[i+1], spec_fz1)
        if ((xy[0] > nf or xy[1]> nf) and (xy2[0] > nf or xy2[1]> nf) ):
            print('both index locations above nyquist frequency')

def return_xy(mode,spec_topo):
    kxky = np.array([])
    for i in range(np.shape(spec_topo)[0]):
        for j in range(np.shape(spec_topo)[1]):
            if spec_topo[i,j] == mode:
                kxky= np.append(kxky,[i,j])

    if len(kxky)> 1:
        return kxky
    else:
        return kxky[0]
```

After sorting by the largest amplitude at the 21st index two amplitude pairs are stored at (127,1) and (1,127) which is above the Nyquist number. How should I interpret this wavenumber? note `return_xy` does same thing as `np.where`

Comment: `fft2` is just the 1D `fft` applied along each dimension. So the ordering is identical. You should not think of positive vs negative frequencies though. The index corresponds to `k` in the DFT equations, and goes from 0 to N-1. The DFT is periodic, such that F[k]==F[k-N]==F[k+N].

Comment: So if the ordering is identical to 1d why do I have amplitude pairs existing at locations greater than the nyquist number as described in my original question?  The numpy documentation uses positive and negative frequencies to describe where the two amplitudes are stored so sorry for the confusion. Also as Im sure your aware F[k]==F[k-N]==F[k+N] in theory is correct but in practice have values with a difference greater than machine epsilon.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment because I didn't like my response...I've typed a similar one above. Well when actually working with the amplitudes they have different magnitudes.

Comment: Ok. First of all, the DFT computes F for k from 0 to N-1. It doesn’t produce a value for, say, k=-3, but F[-3]==F[-3+N], which is in the range 0 to N-1, and this computed. So in a sense the DFT produces values for any k, because of periodicity. This is what I meant when I said that F[k]==F[k-N]==F[k+N]. That statement wasn’t about two different computed values.

Answer (score 2):

I think this bit of code demonstrates how the 2D DFT output of `np.fft.fft2` is organized:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 16
x = np.arange(n) / n * 2 * np.pi
y = np.arange(n) / n * 2 * np.pi

for kx in range(4):
   for ky in range(4):
      f = np.cos(kx * x[None,:] + ky * y[:,None])
      F = np.fft.fft2(f)
      plt.subplot(4, 4, 1 + ky * 4 + kx)
      plt.imshow(np.abs(F))
      plt.axis('off')
      plt.title(f'kx = {kx}, ky = {ky}', fontsize=10)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Output of code above]

We can see that the origin, `kx=0` and `ky=0` is at the top-left of the array. For a horizontal wave with exactly one period in the input, we see we have a pair of peaks at `kx=1` and `kx=N-1` (which is equivalent to `kx=-1`). With two periods in the input, `kx=2` and `kx=-2`, etc. Vertical waves produce the same result but along the vertical axis, and diagonal waves at 45 degrees have the peaks at 45 degrees.

This is the exact same ordering as the 1D DFT (`np.fft.fft`) produces. The 2D DFT is simply the 1D DFT applied along the columns, and then along the rows of the result (or the other way around, it doesn't matter).

---

As for the test shown in the question, it is the superposition of two sine waves (one horizontal and one vertical) multiplied by a round window (a "pillbox" function). In the Fourier domain (continuous world), this corresponds to four impulse functions (two along the horizontal axis for the one sine wave, two along the vertical axis for  the other sine wave), convolved with the Bessel function of the first kind of order 1 (J<sub>1</sub>). Because the sine waves have a low frequency, the four impulse functions are close together, and after the convolution appear as a somewhat wider Bessel function, centered around the origin:

```py
plt.imshow(np.log(np.abs(fz1) + 1e-6))
plt.show()
```

[image: 2D DFT of OP's array]

What we see is the peak centered on the origin (at the top-left corner), with things to the left of the origin wrapped around to the right edge, and things to the top of the origin wrapped around to the bottom edge. Applying `np.fft.fftshift` moves the origin to the middle of the array, yielding a more recognizable shape.